# Difficulty plotting sequence of seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

Whenever I plot a single seaborn heatmap, I get a beautiful result which looks like this:

[image]

But, when I try to plot a sequence of seaborn heatmaps, as follows, I get really strange output:

```
for i in range(5):

    # create mesh grid:
    res = 0.1 ## set resolution
    X,Y = 10, 10
    xy = np.mgrid[0:int(X):res, 0:int(Y):res].reshape(2,-1).T
    values = np.sum(xy,1)
    sns.heatmap(values.reshape((int(X/res),int(Y/res))),cmap="YlGnBu")

    plt.savefig(folder+"_"+str(i)+"_.png")
```

The first image in the sequence is perfect but the second looks like this:

[image]

The third looks like this:

[image]

...and so forth. For reasons I can't understand it appears that seaborn is somehow adding a new colour bar each time.

This problem is non-existent when I set cbar to False but I actually want a colour bar for each individual heatmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you rather want to create 5 individual figures. In order to create a figure, you may use `plt.figure()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

for i in range(5):
    plt.figure()
    # create mesh grid:
    res = 0.1 ## set resolution
    X,Y = 10, 10
    xy = np.mgrid[0:int(X):res, 0:int(Y):res].reshape(2,-1).T
    values = np.sum(xy,1)
    sns.heatmap(values.reshape((int(X/res),int(Y/res))),cmap="YlGnBu")

    plt.savefig("seaborn_"+str(i)+"_.png")

plt.close("All")
```

Alternatively you may clear the figure with `plt.clf()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

for i in range(5):
    plt.clf()
    # create mesh grid:
    res = 0.1 ## set resolution
    X,Y = 10, 10
    xy = np.mgrid[0:int(X):res, 0:int(Y):res].reshape(2,-1).T
    values = np.sum(xy,1)
    sns.heatmap(values.reshape((int(X/res),int(Y/res))),cmap="YlGnBu")

    plt.savefig("seaborn_"+str(i)+"_.png")
```